# modifying url of jquery validation plugin remote method with php framework

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm switching to use [jQuery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org) plugin. I'm working on a remote method to validate a field. The default produced URL adds a query string:

```
http://greenfees.loc/ticketaudits/validateTicket/?ticket=123
```

Within my PHP framework I need the search parameter to be an additional segment of the URL as show below:

```
http://greenfees.loc/ticketaudits/validateTicket/123
```

I can't seem to modify the URL in the call. Here's an extract of effort so far:

```js
rules: {
        ticket: {
            remote: {
                type:"GET",
                url:'/ticketaudits/validateTicket/' + $('#ticket').val(),
            }
        }
    },
```

This though simple replaces the final segment with:

```
http://greenfees.loc/ticketaudits/validateTicket/?ticket=1
```

How can I modify the default URL pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this to work with laravel by changing the code to the following:

```
rules: {
        ticket: {
            remote: {
                type:"POST",
                url:'/ticketaudits/validateTicket',
            }
        }
    },
```

I'm then handling the server side code by getting the parameter from the post request rather than from the get request/url/

It works - so happy with that

now to get the returned messages to work but thats another question!